# Configuring Tomcat to consume webservice over SSL

Tags: tomcat, ssl, web-services, client-server, axis

Which steps should be taken to consume a web service on a remote server over SSL? The application is a Java application using Axis WS Framework running on Tomcat 6.

I'm aware of e.g. the instruction on http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html, which, however seem to mainly describe how to configure the server to accept SSL requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For client connections, it's just like SSL for any other Java application. The fact that it's running in Tomcat doesn't make a difference.

You'll need to specify the correct "https:" endpoint for the web service. If this wasn't the default in the WSDL when you generated the web service client API, you can use an alternate constructor that takes a URL parameter.

If the web service you are accessing doesn't have a certificate issued by a "real" authority that's already recognized by the runtime, you'll need to specify a trust store. The easiest way to do this is by [adding the "javax.net.ssl.trustStore" system property](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#CustomizingStores) when launching the application.

Answer (score 0):

Two common approaches here:
http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/ssl.html
WebLogic has its own stuff:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/security/SSL_client.html#wp1029670